# ObservableStream<List<Type>> convert to List and/or ObservableList<Type> Flutter Mobx

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, mobx, drift

I have setup a sqlite stream from Drift: Stream<List> into my @oberservable class. I can make it an OberserableStream, but I dont understand how to get the list from the stream.

My question is how can I get the list from the ObservableStream and make it an ObservableList or make it an ObeservableList directly from Stream?

Here's what I got wrong so far. I have tried many permutations of this but IDE keeps telling me that its wrong type, wrong .map, wrong `<whatever>`

```
@observable  
ObservableList<TodoDrift> streamTodos() {
    ObservableStream<List<TodoDrift>> list = stObv.asObservable();
    List<TodoDrift> prod = list.map(
            (e) {
               return e.done != true;
              });
    return prod.asObservable();
    // return Future.wait(olStream);
  }
```

Thank you!

FWIW. I also have a Future<List> from Drift and that works fine, I can get the list from there, so that works and I know the data is there.

Comment: and why dont you want to get a "normal" `Stream<List<TodoDrift>>` stream by using [watch()](https://drift.simonbinder.eu/api/drift/selectable/watch) method?

Comment: @pskink Drift is already providing a .watch() method where I have converted to an ObservableStream. If this is not the right process. please let me know. thx.

Comment: @pskink To learn how to work with ObservableStream and ObservableList as alternatiives? Is this not a good use case?

Comment: IDE is right [map](https://pub.dev/documentation/mobx/latest/mobx/ObservableStream/map.html) method returns another `ObservableStream`, not a `List` - if you want a `List` then maybe use [toList](https://pub.dev/documentation/mobx/latest/mobx/ObservableStream/toList.html) and then flatten it to a single `List`

Comment: @pskink I am trying to flatten to list but I dont understand how to extract it from Stream class: IDE keeps error on something like this:     ```List<TodoDrift> list = stObv.where((e) => e..done != true);
    return list;```

Comment: @pskink i hope its clear that i dont understand how to get from Stream<List<TodoDrift>> to List<TodoDrift>. I have tried .map .where .toList(). If you could help me get to List<TodoDrift>, I can convert to ObserableLIst at least and accept your answer.

Comment: heave you read basic `Stream`s stuff: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams? it explains what you can do with streams: how to modify them and how to listen to them - but in general the "normal" flutter way is to use `StreamBuilder` that handles the streams under the hood

Comment: @pskink. thanks for the StreamBuilder rec, but that is the UI piece and I am talking about working within flutter-mobx in state. Here's what I got so far: ```ObservableList<TodoDrift> streamTodos() async {
    var inner;
    await for (final value in stObv) {
      inner = value.map((e) => e.done != true );
      return inner as ObservableList<TodoDrift>;
    }
    return inner;
  }``` But IDE states: "Functions marked as 'async' must have a return type which is a supertype of Future"

Comment: sorry i have no experience with those `ObservableList` stuff

Comment: @pskink Thanks for trying and thanks for the pointers. I'll keep trying....

Comment: ok i have installed `mobx` and i dont think you need `ObservableList<TodoDrift>` at all, see the following code: `ObservableStream<List<int>> stream = Stream.periodic(Durations.extralong4 * 3, (i) => List.generate(4, (j) => 100 * (i + 1) + j))
.take(4)
.asObservable(initialValue: [-1]);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Observer(
builder: (_) {
List<int> v = stream.value!;
return Text('stream $v');
}
);` - here `stream.value` is used inside `Observer` widget like any other [Observable.value](https://pub.dev/documentation/mobx/latest/mobx/Observable/value.html)